# Doubt sufficient condition for differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$ open, $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ Lipschitz.
Given $a\in U$ suppose that for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$

1. There $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)$ and depends linearly of $v$
2. For every path $g:(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)\rightarrow U$ with $g(0)=a$ differentiable in $t=0$ there $(f\circ g)^{\prime}(0)$
One could conclude that $f$ is differentiable at $a$?
I wish that the limit is zero when $\Vert v \Vert \rightarrow  0$ $$\Vert \dfrac{f(a+v)-f(a)-\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)}{\Vert v \Vert}\Vert$$But donot like using conditions 1 and 2 for this
All suggestions are welcome